# Scaling Beamer slide to present as landscape 8.5 x 11 with no borders

Tags: beamer, printing

Update: Changed to `letterpaper` but still has border around the top

I'm attempting to scale my `beamer` slide so that I can print it and it will appear as a 8.5 x 11 when uploaded online without any white boarders. I included `pgfpages` but I'm not getting a desirable result.

How can I get this `beamer` slide scaled so that it will print without borders or white space?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{media9}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\Huge}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{physics}  
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.callouts}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t,plain]{\Large{Math 2212: Supplemental Instruction}}
\begin{columns}

\column{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\vfill


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]


\duck[glasses, xscale=-1];

\node[cloud callout, inner sep= 0pt, fill=pink!50, aspect=2.5,  cloud puff arc=90, text width=3cm, text centered, xshift=1cm, yshift=2cm, callout relative pointer={(-.2,-.5)}] at (bill) {Struggling with\\ Calculus 2?};

\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{-.5cm}
\hspace{1cm}\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]


\fill[green!50!brown!80!black, rotate around={-15:(0.47,1.88)}] (0.47,1.88) ellipse (0.055 and 0.023);
\fill[green!50!brown!80!black, rotate around={15:(0.47,1.83)}] (0.47,1.83) ellipse (0.055 and 0.023);
\duck[jacket=red!30!gray]

\hspace{-3cm}{\node[cloud callout, inner sep= 0pt, fill=cyan!30, aspect=2.5, cloud puff arc=90, text width=3cm, text centered, xshift=-1.3cm, yshift=2cm,] at (bill) {Come to xxx's S.I. Sessions!};}


\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\filldraw[gray!10!white] 
(0.460,1.140) .. controls (0.267, 1.102) and (-0.125,0.657) .. (0.289,0.261) .. controls (0.704,-0.135) and (2.863,0.130) .. (1.818,1.419) .. controls (0.980, 1.000) and ( 1.240,1.378) .. (0.46,0.55) -- cycle;
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\draw (1.29,1.82) -- (1.19,1.77) -- (1.1,1.74) -- (1,1.74);
\fill[green!50!brown!80!black, rotate around={15:(1,1.72)}] (1,1.72) ellipse (0.055 and 0.023);
\fill[green!50!brown!80!black, rotate around={18:(1.1,1.716)}] (1.1,1.716) ellipse (0.055 and 0.023);
\fill[green!50!brown!80!black, rotate around={45:(1.2,1.75)}] (1.2,1.75) ellipse (0.055 and 0.023);
\fill[green!50!brown!80!black, rotate around={70:(1.3,1.8)}] (1.3,1.8) ellipse (0.055 and 0.023);
\fill[green!50!brown!80!black, rotate around={-25:(1,1.76)}] (1,1.76) ellipse (0.055 and 0.023);
\fill[green!50!brown!80!black, rotate around={-25:(1.1,1.76)}] (1.1,1.76) ellipse (0.055 and 0.023);
\fill[green!50!brown!80!black, rotate around={-20:(1.19,1.79)}] (1.19,1.79) ellipse (0.055 and 0.023);
\fill[green!50!brown!80!black, rotate around={10:(1.27,1.84)}] (1.27,1.84) ellipse (0.055 and 0.023);
\end{tikzpicture}
 

\column{.5\textwidth}  
\centering

\large{\textbf{\textit{S.I. SESSION'S ARE AVAILABLE}}}\vspace{.2cm}

\small{\textit{Course\dotfill MATH 2212}\\}
\small{\textit{Professor\dotfill Dr. xxx}\\}
\small{\textit{Time\dotfill 9am - 10:45am}\\}
\small{\textit{CRN Number\dotfill xxx}\\}\vspace{.2cm}
         
\textbf{S.I. Session: \textit{NE 0360} \\ Monday 4pm - 5pm\\\vspace{.2cm}}
\textbf{Q\&A Sesssion: \textit{NE 0360} \\ Tuesday 5pm - 6pm\\\vspace{.2cm}}
\textbf{S.I. Session: \textit{NE 0360} \\ Thursday 5pm - 6pm\\\vspace{.2cm}}

Instructor: \hfill xxx\\
E-Mail: \hfill xxx
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I've added the below code but my end result is the following. How do I fill in the title to fit the page?

```
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[letterpaper,landscape]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are using `a4paper`, whose dimensions are `8-1/4 x 11-3/4 in`. You should use `letterpaper`, whose dimensions are `8.5 x 11 in`. This will eliminate the white space.

Replace this:

```
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
```

By this:

```
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[letterpaper,landscape]
```

***EDIT:***
I'm not sure this, or the solution I proposed above are the best/optimal solutions (i've never used the beamer class or pgfpages). But to remove the space above the frame title, I did find this:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{-0.15cm}}{}
```

Comment: I posted an update. You can see what happens when I update the option to letterpaper. How do I get rid of the boarder on top?

Comment: Check out the update on my answer.

Comment: Thank you for posting an update. While these solutions did correct the pdf not having white space. It still prints with that white space. I will post an update when I have a second.

Comment: You have to add the line of code in my edit after you use `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]` for it to work.